# Tips for Creating Summary Count of Value in other Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple tables with a status column in each.  I want to display a summary of the counts of each status per table.  Something like this:

```
=============================================

Status   |  Table A  |  Table B  |  Table C  |

Status A |   3     |     8     |    2      |

Status B |     5     |     7     |    4      |

==============================================
```

I need help getting started as I'm not sure how to approach this issue.  I can do simple COUNT functions like:

```
SELECT status, count(status) from TABLE_A group by status
```

But I'm not sure how to populate the data in the form I want or how to, if possible, use the table names as the column headers.  I'd appreciate a point in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

could be using left join

```
 select t.status, a.cnt A, b.cnt B,c.cnt C
from( 
  select  status 
  from  tableA 
  union 
  select  status 
  from  tableB
  select  status 
  from  tableC

  ) t 
  left join (
      select status, count(*) cnt
      from  tableA
      group by status 
  ) a ON  on t.status  = a.status 

  left join (
      select status, count(*) cnt
      from  tableB
      group by status 
  ) b ON  on t.status  = b.status 
  left join (
      select status, count(*) cnt
      from  tableC
      group by status 
  ) c ON  on t.status  = c.status
```

Comment: The third alias should be C :)

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this and I'm getting the format I need, but the count for each column is the same.  I tried using 'distinct' but that didn't fix it.  Any ideas on how to get each column to only count the values for its table?

Answer (score 0):

May be try doing left joins after you have calculated counts for each table separately.Something like:

```
select distinct t1.status, 
  count(t1.status) as [tableA], 
   t2.TableB, 
   t3.TableC from Table A t1
left join (
         select distinct status, 
         count(status) as [TableB] from Table B 
         group by status
) t2 on t1.status=t2.status
left join (
         select distinct status, 
         count(status) as [TableC] from Table C 
         group by status
) t3 on t1.status=t3.status
group by t1.Status
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select status, sum(a) as a, sum(b) as b, sum(c) as c
from ((select status, count(*) as a, 0 as b, 0 as c
       from tablea
       group by status
      ) union all
      (select status, 0, count(*), 0 
       from tableb
       group by status
      ) union all
      (select status, 0, 0, count(*)
       from tablea
       group by status
      )
     ) abc
group by status;
```

This ensures that all rows appear, even when one or more tables are missing some values of status.